# Differentiation, .diff() doesn't give expected output

Tags: python, math, sympy, differentiation

I writing a bit of code, but the problem is found here:

```
[IN>] from sympy import*

[IN>] t= Symbol('t')
      x1 = Function('x1')(t)
      x2 = Function('x2')(t)
      y1 = Function('y1')(t)
      y2 = Function('y2')(t)
```

I define my expression:

```
[IN>] f = (x1.diff(t)*y2.diff(t)- x2.diff(t)*y1.diff(t))
```

Then, when differentiating the expresion `f` wrt. the factors of the first summand I get the 
*unexpected* output:

```
[IN>] f.diff(y2.diff(t))

[OUT>] Subs(Derivative(x1(t), t), (_xi_2,), (Derivative(y2(t), t),))
```

but if I differentiate wrt. the second summand factors

```
[IN>] f.diff(y1.diff(t))

[OUT>] -Derivative(x2(t), t)
```

I get the desired and *expected* result. I'm totally baffled by this. Still more, if I change the order of the summands, I get the same result:

```
[IN>] (-x2.diff(t)*y1.diff(t)+x1.diff(t)*y2.diff(t) ).diff(y2.diff(t))

[OUT>] Subs(Derivative(x1(t), t), (_xi_2,), (Derivative(y2(t), t),))

[IN>] (-x2.diff(t)*y1.diff(t)+x1.diff(t)*y2.diff(t) ).diff(y1.diff(t))

[OUT>] -Derivative(x2(t), t)
```

But if I exchange the minus `-``sign, the propeblem is now in the other pair of functions:

```
[IN>] (+x2.diff(t)*y1.diff(t)-x1.diff(t)*y2.diff(t) ).diff(y1.diff(t))

[OUT>] Subs(Derivative(x2(t), t), (_xi_2,), (Derivative(y1(t), t),))
```

Comment: @Mitch: I had a problem with my connection, and submited the question to early.

Comment: `doit` is your answer, but I would consider this to be a bug in SymPy. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11467.

Comment: @asmeurer I thought that that might be a problem. Thanks for putting it forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to get the *desired* result I only had to ad `.doit()`, as it was returning my the `Subs()` function.

```
(+x2.diff(t)*y1.diff(t)-x1.diff(t)*y2.diff(t) ).diff(y1.diff(t)).doit()

Derivative(x2(t), t)
```